# Changing the name and value of the select element according to the radio value in the form

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing an order form. I'm stuck at this point and I need your help.

Radios with the name "id" in the form below are different products. I need to change the name and value of the select element depending on the product.

```html
<form action="?cmd=cart" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="make" value="order" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cycle" value="m" />


  <label for="id" class="styled">Packade</label>
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" checked="checked" name="id" value="16" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" checked="checked" name="id" value="17" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" checked="checked" name="id" value="18" />


  <label for="custom[294]" class="styled">OS</label>
  <select name="custom[294]" class="form-select">
    <option value="default_option">Select</option>
    <option data-val="1182" value="1182">CentOS 7</option>
    <option data-val="1183" value="1183">CentOS 8 Stream</option>
    <option data-val="1188" value="1188">CentOS 9 Stream</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/berkaybulut/pen/oNaRKeV)

For example;

If the radio value is 17;
The name of the select element is: `custom[294]` >> `custom[295]`
The value of the select element is `value="1182"` >>> `value="1183"`

should be updated.

in the same way
If the radio value is 18;
Name of select element: `custom[294]` >> `custom[296]`
The value of the select element is `value="1182"` >>> `value="1184"`

should be updated.

I don't know how to do this.

I tried several js attempts, failed.

Comment: `<label>`'s `for` attribute should be an `id`, not a `name`.

Comment: Where are these magic numbers coming from? Any specific logic to it?

Comment: custom[test] values are generated by script. Therefore I am trying to create a static order form.

Comment: And you want to keep the same options of `select` for different value of radio button group?

Answer (score 0):

Here see if this going to help you.

What I did is add an array of objects `productsArray`.

```
const productsArray = [
            {id: 16, name: "custom[294]", options: [{id: 1182, text: "text1182"}, {id: 1183, text: "text1183"}, {id: 1184, text: "text1184"}]}, 
            {id: 17, name: "custom[295]", options: [{id: 1185, text: "text1185"}, {id: 1186, text: "text1186"}, {id: 1187, text: "text1187"}]},
            {id: 18, name: "custom[296]", options: [{id: 1188, text: "text1188"}, {id: 1189, text: "text1189"}, {id: 1190, text: "text1190"}]}
        ];
```

As you can see I added the options values (id) and text randomly.

And added an event Listener for all radio inputs.

```
const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="id"]');
const selectItem = document.querySelector('select[class="form-select"]');
for(const radioButton of radioButtons){
   radioButton.addEventListener('change', showSelected);
}
```

Finally this is the body of the function `showSelected`.

```
          function showSelected(e) {
                if (this.checked) {
                    console.log(this.value);
                    let SelectedObj = productsArray.find(o => o.id == this.value);
                    selectItem.setAttribute("name",SelectedObj.name);
                    selectItem.innerHTML = "";
                    selectItem.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<option value="default_option">Select</option>');
                    for (let i=0; i < SelectedObj.options.length; i++){
                        selectItem.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option data-val="${SelectedObj.options[i].id}" value="${SelectedObj.options[i].id}">${SelectedObj.options[i].text}</option>`);
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the final code (after edit to use more then one select.):

```js
const productsArray = {CentOS: [
            {id: 16, name: "custom[294]", options: [{id: 1182, text: "CentOS 7"}, {id: 1183, text: "CentOS 8 Stream"}, {id: 1188, text: "CentOS 9 Stream"}]},
            {id: 17, name: "custom[232]", options: [{id: 1198, text: "CentOS 7"}, {id: 1199, text: "CentOS 8 Stream"}, {id: 1204, text: "CentOS 9 Stream"}]},
            {id: 21, name: "custom[241]", options: [{id: 1214, text: "CentOS 7"}, {id: 1215, text: "CentOS 8 Stream"}, {id: 1220, text: "CentOS 9 Stream"}]},
            {id: 22, name: "custom[250]", options: [{id: 1230, text: "CentOS 7"}, {id: 1231, text: "CentOS 8 Stream"}, {id: 1236, text: "CentOS 9 Stream"}]},
            {id: 23, name: "custom[259]", options: [{id: 1246, text: "CentOS 7"}, {id: 1247, text: "CentOS 8 Stream"}, {id: 1252, text: "CentOS 9 Stream"}]},
            {id: 24, name: "custom[268]", options: [{id: 1262, text: "CentOS 7"}, {id: 1263, text: "CentOS 8 Stream"}, {id: 1268, text: "CentOS 9 Stream"}]},
            {id: 25, name: "custom[277]", options: [{id: 1278, text: "CentOS 7"}, {id: 1279, text: "CentOS 8 Stream"}, {id: 1284, text: "CentOS 9 Stream"}]},
            {id: 26, name: "custom[286]", options: [{id: 1294, text: "CentOS 7"}, {id: 1295, text: "CentOS 8 Stream"}, {id: 1300, text: "CentOS 9 Stream"}]}
        ],
        AlmaLinux: [
            {id: 16, name: "custom[294]", options: [{id: 1186, text: "AlmaLinux 8"}, {id: 1187, text: "AlmaLinux 9"}]},
            {id: 17, name: "custom[232]", options: [{id: 1202, text: "AlmaLinux 8"}, {id: 1203, text: "AlmaLinux 9"}]},
            {id: 21, name: "custom[241]", options: [{id: 1218, text: "AlmaLinux 8"}, {id: 1219, text: "AlmaLinux 9"}]},
            {id: 22, name: "custom[250]", options: [{id: 1234, text: "AlmaLinux 8"}, {id: 1235, text: "AlmaLinux 9"}]},
            {id: 23, name: "custom[259]", options: [{id: 1250, text: "AlmaLinux 8"}, {id: 1251, text: "AlmaLinux 9"}]},
            {id: 24, name: "custom[268]", options: [{id: 1266, text: "AlmaLinux 8"}, {id: 1267, text: "AlmaLinux 9"}]},
            {id: 25, name: "custom[277]", options: [{id: 1282, text: "AlmaLinux 8"}, {id: 1283, text: "AlmaLinux 9"}]},
            {id: 26, name: "custom[286]", options: [{id: 1298, text: "AlmaLinux 8"}, {id: 1299, text: "AlmaLinux 9"}]}
        ],
        Debian: [
            {id: 16, name: "custom[294]", options: [{id: 1191, text: "Debian 9"}, {id: 1459, text: "Debian 10"}, {id: 1190, text: "Debian 11"}, {id: 1189, text: "Debian 12"}]},
            {id: 17, name: "custom[232]", options: [{id: 1207, text: "Debian 9"}, {id: 1460, text: "Debian 10"}, {id: 1206, text: "Debian 11"}, {id: 1205, text: "Debian 12"}]},
            {id: 21, name: "custom[241]", options: [{id: 1223, text: "Debian 9"}, {id: 1461, text: "Debian 10"}, {id: 1222, text: "Debian 11"}, {id: 1221, text: "Debian 12"}]},
            {id: 22, name: "custom[250]", options: [{id: 1239, text: "Debian 9"}, {id: 1462, text: "Debian 10"}, {id: 1238, text: "Debian 11"}, {id: 1237, text: "Debian 12"}]},
            {id: 23, name: "custom[259]", options: [{id: 1255, text: "Debian 9"}, {id: 1463, text: "Debian 10"}, {id: 1254, text: "Debian 11"}, {id: 1253, text: "Debian 12"}]},
            {id: 24, name: "custom[268]", options: [{id: 1271, text: "Debian 9"}, {id: 1464, text: "Debian 10"}, {id: 1270, text: "Debian 11"}, {id: 1269, text: "Debian 12"}]},
            {id: 25, name: "custom[277]", options: [{id: 1287, text: "Debian 9"}, {id: 1465, text: "Debian 10"}, {id: 1286, text: "Debian 11"}, {id: 1285, text: "Debian 12"}]},
            {id: 26, name: "custom[286]", options: [{id: 1303, text: "Debian 9"}, {id: 1466, text: "Debian 10"}, {id: 1302, text: "Debian 11"}, {id: 1301, text: "Debian 12"}]}
        ],
        Ubuntu: [
            {id: 16, name: "custom[294]", options: [{id: 1412, text: "Ubuntu 18.04"}, {id: 1413, text: "Ubuntu 20.04"}, {id: 1414, text: "Ubuntu 22.04"}, {id: 1415, text: "Ubuntu 23.04"}]},
            {id: 17, name: "custom[232]", options: [{id: 1417, text: "Ubuntu 18.04"}, {id: 1418, text: "Ubuntu 20.04"}, {id: 1419, text: "Ubuntu 22.04"}, {id: 1420, text: "Ubuntu 23.04"}]},
            {id: 21, name: "custom[241]", options: [{id: 1422, text: "Ubuntu 18.04"}, {id: 1423, text: "Ubuntu 20.04"}, {id: 1424, text: "Ubuntu 22.04"}, {id: 1425, text: "Ubuntu 23.04"}]},
            {id: 22, name: "custom[250]", options: [{id: 1427, text: "Ubuntu 18.04"}, {id: 1428, text: "Ubuntu 20.04"}, {id: 1429, text: "Ubuntu 22.04"}, {id: 1430, text: "Ubuntu 23.04"}]},
            {id: 23, name: "custom[259]", options: [{id: 1432, text: "Ubuntu 18.04"}, {id: 1433, text: "Ubuntu 20.04"}, {id: 1434, text: "Ubuntu 22.04"}, {id: 1435, text: "Ubuntu 23.04"}]},
            {id: 24, name: "custom[268]", options: [{id: 1437, text: "Ubuntu 18.04"}, {id: 1438, text: "Ubuntu 20.04"}, {id: 1439, text: "Ubuntu 22.04"}, {id: 1440, text: "Ubuntu 23.04"}]},
            {id: 25, name: "custom[277]", options: [{id: 1442, text: "Ubuntu 18.04"}, {id: 1443, text: "Ubuntu 20.04"}, {id: 1444, text: "Ubuntu 22.04"}, {id: 1445, text: "Ubuntu 23.04"}]},
            {id: 26, name: "custom[286]", options: [{id: 1447, text: "Ubuntu 18.04"}, {id: 1448, text: "Ubuntu 20.04"}, {id: 1449, text: "Ubuntu 22.04"}, {id: 1450, text: "Ubuntu 23.04"}]}
        ],
        Fedora: [
            {id: 16, name: "custom[294]", options: [{id: 1194, text: "Fedora 38"}]},
            {id: 17, name: "custom[232]", options: [{id: 1210, text: "Fedora 38"}]},
            {id: 21, name: "custom[241]", options: [{id: 1226, text: "Fedora 38"}]},
            {id: 22, name: "custom[250]", options: [{id: 1242, text: "Fedora 38"}]},
            {id: 23, name: "custom[259]", options: [{id: 1258, text: "Fedora 38"}]},
            {id: 24, name: "custom[268]", options: [{id: 1274, text: "Fedora 38"}]},
            {id: 25, name: "custom[277]", options: [{id: 1290, text: "Fedora 38"}]},
            {id: 26, name: "custom[286]", options: [{id: 1306, text: "Fedora 38"}]}
        ],
        openSUSE: [
            {id: 16, name: "custom[294]", options: [{id: 2046, text: "openSUSE Leap 15.4"}, {id: 2054, text: "SUSE Linux Enterprise"}]},
            {id: 17, name: "custom[232]", options: [{id: 2047, text: "openSUSE Leap 15.4"}, {id: 2055, text: "SUSE Linux Enterprise"}]},
            {id: 21, name: "custom[241]", options: [{id: 2048, text: "openSUSE Leap 15.4"}, {id: 2056, text: "SUSE Linux Enterprise"}]},
            {id: 22, name: "custom[250]", options: [{id: 2049, text: "openSUSE Leap 15.4"}, {id: 2057, text: "SUSE Linux Enterprise"}]},
            {id: 23, name: "custom[259]", options: [{id: 2050, text: "openSUSE Leap 15.4"}, {id: 2058, text: "SUSE Linux Enterprise"}]},
            {id: 24, name: "custom[268]", options: [{id: 2051, text: "openSUSE Leap 15.4"}, {id: 2059, text: "SUSE Linux Enterprise"}]},
            {id: 25, name: "custom[277]", options: [{id: 2052, text: "openSUSE Leap 15.4"}, {id: 2060, text: "SUSE Linux Enterprise"}]},
            {id: 26, name: "custom[286]", options: [{id: 2053, text: "openSUSE Leap 15.4"}, {id: 2061, text: "SUSE Linux Enterprise"}]}
        ],
        archlinux: [
            {id: 16, name: "custom[294]", options: [{id: 2062, text: "Arch Linux"}]},
            {id: 17, name: "custom[232]", options: [{id: 2063, text: "Arch Linux"}]},
            {id: 21, name: "custom[241]", options: [{id: 2064, text: "Arch Linux"}]},
            {id: 22, name: "custom[250]", options: [{id: 2065, text: "Arch Linux"}]},
            {id: 23, name: "custom[259]", options: [{id: 2066, text: "Arch Linux"}]},
            {id: 24, name: "custom[268]", options: [{id: 2067, text: "Arch Linux"}]},
            {id: 25, name: "custom[277]", options: [{id: 2068, text: "Arch Linux"}]},
            {id: 26, name: "custom[286]", options: [{id: 2069, text: "Arch Linux"}]}
        ]
        };
        const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="id"]');
        
        const centosSelectItem = document.querySelector('select[id="centos"]');
        const almalinuxSelectItem = document.querySelector('select[id="almalinux"]');
        const debianSelectItem = document.querySelector('select[id="debian"]');
        const ubuntuSelectItem = document.querySelector('select[id="ubuntu"]');
        const fedoraSelectItem = document.querySelector('select[id="fedora"]');
        const suseSelectItem = document.querySelector('select[id="suse"]');
        const archlinuxSelectItem = document.querySelector('select[id="archlinux"]');
        
        for(const radioButton of radioButtons){
            radioButton.addEventListener('change', showSelected);
        }     
        function showSelected(e) {
            if (this.checked) {
                console.log(this.value);
                
                changeSelectNameAndHTML(centosSelectItem, productsArray.CentOS, this.value);
                changeSelectNameAndHTML(almalinuxSelectItem, productsArray.AlmaLinux, this.value);
                changeSelectNameAndHTML(debianSelectItem, productsArray.Debian, this.value);
                changeSelectNameAndHTML(ubuntuSelectItem, productsArray.Ubuntu, this.value);
                changeSelectNameAndHTML(fedoraSelectItem, productsArray.Fedora, this.value);
                changeSelectNameAndHTML(suseSelectItem, productsArray.openSUSE, this.value);
                changeSelectNameAndHTML(suseSelectItem, productsArray.archlinux, this.value);
            }
        }
        function changeSelectNameAndHTML(selectItem, products, radioValue){
            let SelectedObj = products.find(o => o.id == radioValue);
            
            selectItem.setAttribute("name",SelectedObj.name);
            selectItem.innerHTML = "";
            selectItem.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<option value="default_option">Select</option>');
            
            for (let i=0; i < SelectedObj.options.length; i++){
                selectItem.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option data-val="${SelectedObj.options[i].id}" value="${SelectedObj.options[i].id}">${SelectedObj.options[i].text}</option>`);
            }
        }
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="id" class="styled">Packade</label>
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" checked="checked" name="id" value="16" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="id" value="17" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="id" value="21" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="id" value="22" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="id" value="23" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="id" value="24" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="id" value="25" />
  <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="id" value="26" />


 <select name="custom[294]" class="form-select" id="centos">
    <option value="default_option">Select</option>
    <option data-val="1182" value="1182">CentOS 7</option>
    <option data-val="1183" value="1183">CentOS 8 Stream</option>
    <option data-val="1188" value="1188">CentOS 9 Stream</option>
  </select>
 <select name="custom[294]" class="form-select" id="ubuntu">
   <option value="default_option">Select</option>
   <option data-val="1412" value="1412">Ubuntu 18.04</option>
   <option data-val="1413" value="1413">Ubuntu 20.04</option>
     <option data-val="1414" value="1414">Ubuntu 22.04</option>
     <option data-val="1415" value="1415">Ubuntu 23.04</option>
  </select>
  <select name="custom[294]" class="form-select" id="debian">
    <option value="default_option">Select</option>
    <option data-val="1191" value="1191">Debian 9</option>
    <option data-val="1459" value="1459">Debian 10</option>
        <option data-val="1190" value="1190">Debian 11</option>
        <option data-val="1189" value="1189">Debian 12</option>
  </select>
  <select name="custom[294]" class="form-select" id="almalinux">
    <option value="default_option">Select</option>
    <option data-val="1186" value="1186">AlmaLinux 8</option>
        <option data-val="1187" value="1187">AlmaLinux 9</option>
  </select>
  <select name="custom[294]" class="form-select" id="fedora">
    <option value="default_option">Select</option>
    <option data-val="1194" value="1194">Fedora 38</option>
  </select>
  <select name="custom[294]" class="form-select" id="suse">
    <option value="default_option">Select</option>
    <option data-val="2046" value="2046">openSUSE 15.4</option>
        <option data-val="2054" value="2054">SUSE Enterprise</option>
  </select>
 <select name="custom[294]" class="form-select" id="archlinux">
    <option value="default_option">Select</option>
    <option data-val="2062" value="2062">Arch Linux</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot, but I have one more minor problem.
For some reason I will need to use more than one select. When I repeat the loop I get an error in the console output
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'productsArray' has already been declared"

Comment: https://codepen.io/berkaybulut/pen/oNaRKeV

Comment: Yes you are declaring 'productsArray' more then once, not only it all variables you coped and pasted the variables.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show you simple way to do it.